# Permissions in Android

Tags: android, permissions, request, android-manifest

I have a doubt:

When you set a permission in android manifest, like

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Are you directly enabling GPS location, or you need to request it on the MainActivity (for example)?

I have done some examples and found out that if I don't set the uses-permission in the android manifest, I can't request that permission, and it fells that I don´t have that permission. But with other examples I found on the internet, I have seen that they only set the permission in the android manifest, not requesting it later in the Activity, as if this works.

So, what is the goal of setting the uses-permission in android manifest, and is this enough to have a permission, or I have to request it later in an Activity?

Comment: You always need to request it in the manifest. On Android 6.0+, you *also* need to request it at runtime. See [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/overview).

Comment: @CommonsWare so, I have to request all of them in the manifest. And then, all of them will be granted, except for the risky one where I have to explictly request them at runtime?

Comment: What happens with a permission is complex and depends on a few factors. Your description fits for the distinction between `normal` and `dangerous` permissions (referring to their `protectionLevel` values).

Answer (score 0):

The point of having permissions is for Android to protect user data and privacy. There are so many ways you can use information such as user GPS and access to the user data inside the phone. The permissions by default are locked out to protect the user. So in order to use the data, you have to ask for the permissions from the user.

The only permissions that you don't need to explicitly ask during runtime are those that are safe to use without affecting the user data and privacy.

Check this link.
[Android permissions explained by official documentation](http://You%20should%20look%20at%20firestore%20Security%20rules.%20%20%20[Firestore%20Security%20Rules][1]%20%20%20%20%20[1]:%20https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started%20%20You%20will%20be%20able%20to%20limit%20and%20control%20who%20has%20to%20what%20data.https://)